# ASP.net + Login with facebook and aspnetdb authorisation

Tags: asp.net, facebook, aspnetdb

I am using the Facebook login api in my website, currently I am checking if the FB userid exist in my SQL Server database, if it does, the user is allowed to access my website else he will be directed to the Facebook registration plugin page.

The thing is I am also using aspnetdb which in my web.config authorisation, I block all users accept for users who are logged in and authenticated by the aspnetdb membership provider, hence my problem is for users who uses logs in successfully with Facebook gets block by my app's non-fb login page. How should I go about authenticating users who logs in via Facebook? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook login/registration API provides you with the FBUserid, it should be stored in your SQL server DB against the user. If a new user comes to your website and registers via FB, you should generate corresponding user in your database too with some default password (random and different for each user) You can provide the functionality that, if a user registered with FB wishes to user your application's login, you should send him the default password via email and ask him/her to change on first login.